# Passing props as ref and as method to child or sibling in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a AndroidDrawer using DrawerLayoutAndroid and ToolbarAndroid of react-native.
When the hamburger icon on the toolbar is clicked, the drawer should open.

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid ref={(element) => {
      this.drawer=element;
    }}
          drawerWidth={300}
          drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
          renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
          <Toolbar toolbarText="XYZ" drawer={this.drawer}/>
</DrawerLayoutAndroid>
```

//Another file exported as Toolbar

```
<ToolbarAndroid
  navIcon={DrawerIcon}
  onIconClicked={() => {

    this.props.drawer.openDrawer();

  }}
    title={this.props.toolbarText}
    style={[styles.toolbar,{backgroundColor:col}]}
    />
```

But when I press on the toolbar icon it says *undefined is not a function for "_this2.props.drawer.openDrawer"*.

Alternatively when I make a method as

```
openMydrawer(){
this.drawer.openDrawer();
```

}

and then pass it as props to Toolbar as `drawer=this.openMyDrawer.bind(this)` and then call it from Toolbar as `this.props.openMyDrawer` it works just fine...

Can someone explain why undefined is passed when I directly pass reference to Toolbar **as objects are passed as reference not by value, as soon as this.drawer gets a value that value should be reflected down to its children or siblings for that matter.**

Answer (score 1):

The layout function isn't causing a re-render, so when you rendered `Toolbar` your `this.drawer` was undefined since the layout function wasn't called at this point.
Your other method worked because `this.drawer` was evaluated at the moment the function ran (button pressed) and not when the component was rendering.

To pass the ref as a prop, you would have to trigger another render, ideally by putting the ref in the state. Like this:

```
render() {
    <DrawerLayoutAndroid 
            ref={(element) => this.setState({drawer:element})}
            drawerWidth={300}
            drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
            renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
            <Toolbar toolbarText="XYZ" drawer={this.state.drawer}/>
    </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
}
```

You should take into account that the drawer ref will be undefined for in `Toolbar`'s first render.

Comment: What I don't understand is that JavaScript passes objects as references...so even if initially the ref was undefined, when ever it's value changes should that not be reflected to every element that uses it, as the value passed is just a reference to a single 'DrawerLayoutAndroid' object?
My confusion arises from pass by value and pass by reference in JavaScript.

Comment: @Abhishek It's not very special for javascript, you just need to grasp how a value and reference type work. It's the same as Java and C# in that regard.